# Javascript Validation in WordPress not working for Google form

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

My Goal was to redirect a user after filling out a Google form on Wordpress. I have managed to do this and restyle the form with css. I have used the following tutorial: [how-to-style-google-forms-and-redirect-it-to-your-desired-thankyou-page](http://trickspocket.com/how-to-style-google-forms-and-redirect-it-to-your-desired-thankyou-page/)

The problem is that I can not get my custom javascript validation to work in Wordpress. I have tested the code locally and replicated it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Kipdeeds/bg50qytx/15/).

```
<body>
<h1 id="heading">This Is Kip's Form Test</h1>
<form action="http://www.wikipedia.org" method="GET" onsubmit="return(validate());">
    <ul id="special-list">
        <li>First name:<input type="text" name="entry.198534167" value=""></li> 
        <li>Last name:<input type="text" name=","entry.641095175" value=""></li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="sex" value="male" checked>Male</li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="sex" value="female">Female</li>
    </ul>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
var errors = [];
function validate(){
  var check_name = /^[a-zA-Z ]{2,30}$/;
  var elements = ["entry.198534167","entry.641095175"]; 
  var first_name = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
  var last_name = document.forms[0].elements[1].value;
  if(!check_name.test(first_name)){
    errors[errors.length] = "Your first name was not entered correctly. Use   letters A - Z.";
    document.forms[0].elements[0].focus() ;
    }
 if(!check_name.test(last_name)){
    errors[errors.length] = "Your last name was not entered correctly. Use    letters A - Z.";
   }
if (errors.length > 0) {
  reportErrors(errors);
  return false;
  }
return true;
}

function reportErrors(errors){
  var msg = "Please Enter Valid Data...\n";
  for (var i = 0; i<errors.length; i++) {
  numError = i + 1;
  msg += "\n" + numError + ". " + errors[i];
  }
alert(msg);
}
```

I have tried linking the my javascript file in the head, enqueue in my child theme functions.php file, and lastly in the body of the page template file.

Lastly, I know that that my javascript page is being added because it shows up in the developer tools resources listing. I have also tried an alert message that works when the document is ready. However, the validation still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

After running my javascript through jslint and making sure that there were no fatal flaws, I found my error in the html form. The code I provide in the jsfiddle worked because the function `validate()` was supplied in the form attribute `onsubmit=""`.

On WordPress in the html I had `onsubmit="submitted=true;"`. I believe this was the code copied from the Google Form. My fiddle had the correct html (I did not need the `;`) and the WordPress code I had was incorrect.